# Static List within a Generic Class

Tags: c#, generics, static-members

I have the following code (a simple example of a more complex project) where I have a static 'master' list of object typed lists.

If you step through the code I was expecting that when the second referenceManager3 type is created, via the constructor, that the _masterList would then contain both the String and Object lists. However it does not.

I assume this is due to the fact that each instance of ReferenceManager3 are actually different class types because of the generic type definition. Am I correct in thinking that?

How can I make this work?

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ReferenceManager3<string> StringManager = new ReferenceManager3<string>();
        ReferenceManager3<object> IntManager = new ReferenceManager3<object>();
    }
}

class ReferenceManager3<T> where T : class //IReferenceTracking
{
    // Static list containing a reference to all Typed Lists
    static List<IList> _masterList = new List<IList>();

    // Object Typed List
    private List<T> _list = null;

    public ReferenceManager3()
    {
        // Create the new Typed List
        _list = new List<T>();

        // Add it to the Static Master List
        _masterList.Add(_list); // <<< break here on the second call.
    }
}
```

Comment: Out of interest, why is this something you want to do?  I think there might well be better alternative if you can provide some context.

Comment: A workaround would be to place the `_masterlist` in a different class.

Comment: @TheGrovesy clearly you assumed that _masterList would have been the same instance for both your objects, however there will be different static objects for different instances of your generic class. What is that you're trying to achieve?

Comment: It relates to another post I created regarding deletable objects. I want a way of managing all my 'deletable' objects. What I mean by this is that all objects used here are of the same Interface, each class implements an 'hasBeenDeleted' function. When a static 'Delete' funcion gets called in the ReferenceManager3 it will use the masterList to call all object 'hasBeenDeleted' functions. Then each object un-reference the deleted object (if its relevent)

Comment: They are indeed diferent. Each instantiated has a different entry in TypeSpec table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can derive your generic class from a non-generic (abstract) base class:

```
abstract class ReferenceManager3
{
    // Static list containing a reference to all Typed Lists
    protected static List<IList> _masterList = new List<IList>();
}

class ReferenceManager3<T> : ReferenceManager3 where T : class //IReferenceTracking
{

    // Object Typed List
    private List<T> _list = null;

    public ReferenceManager3()
    {
        // Create the new Typed List
        _list = new List<T>();

        // Add it to the Static Master List
        _masterList.Add(_list); // <<< break here on the second call.
    }
}
```

Comment: i thought abstract class should need at least one abstract method :3

Comment: @Desperado no, but vice versa is valid. At least one abstract method needs an abstract class

Comment: The difference is that - as the OP supposed - the two created object belongs to different classes and have different static variables. By using a base class both classes can share a static variable.

Comment: @RoyalBg Because the static masterList is contained in a single class type 'ReferenceManager3'. Whereas before, in my OP, it was inside the 'ReferenceManager3<T>' which means two instances with different types are actually difference classes, as Phate01 and HimBromBeere confirmed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your assumption is right, `ReferenceManager3<string>` and `ReferenceManager3<object>` are different classes that do not have anything in common. So both classes also have their own (static) lists.

However you can create a non-generic abstract-class containing the static list. Now simply implement this class from your generic one as Fratyx allready mentions.